# Apache tomcat installation issue in windows 7

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat7

I have downloaded Apache-tomcat from link http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi and extracted it to `C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.61`, then I executed  `startup.bat` (located in \bin). Command execution starts and it stops showing message :

> INFO: Server startup in 850 ms

and stuck there.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

1. It's a good practice to extract Tomcat archive in a folder location **without** blank spaces. In your case the possible problematic place is the folder **Program Files**. Depending on the OS and environment, this may or may not cause problems.
2. The easiest way to check if Tomcat is running normally is to access http://localhost:8080. You should see web page rendered by the root Tomcat application.
3. Highly unlikely, but it may turn out that the downloaded archive file is broken. You may try to download it again.
4. I always use console (cmd) to run Tomcat instead of double-clicking on the startup.bat script. In this way I'm able to read all logged messages.